# Ability to view all flags waiting for review

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, flag-history

Usually, the *Other* flags take a while to be reviewed.  If one flags rather frequently, then it's not uncommon to have multiple flags waiting for review.  At times, it's a bit of a pain to navigate through several pages of flagged posts in order to find which ones are *Waiting for review*.

> `http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/<id>?page=<n>`

Could we have a link for

> *n* Waiting for review

to a different page, say `http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/<id>/waiting`, that lists those.

Answer (score 6):

This has been completed in the latest build (thank to Oded). The sidebar stats on the flag history page will now allow filtering for "waiting for review".